# Regular expression to find "src" attribute of HTML "img" element in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string, inside of that I have an image:

```
"<p><img src="http://yahoo.com/testfolder/userdata/editoruploadimages/confused man.jpg" /></p>"
```

I could not fetch the image URL with my regular expression. My code is:

```
preg_match_all("/src=([^\\s]+)/", $questArr_str, $images);
```

This code stops its execution when it encounters the space in the image name. It only returns `"http://yahoo.com/testfolder/userdata/editoruploadimages/confused`

The returned string should be:
`"http://yahoo.com/testfolder/userdata/editoruploadimages/confused man.jpg"`

Comment: You are searching only for non whitespace characters in your regex, why should it match the space? Regex is not the best solution to match html, better to use a html/dom parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank every one for helping me out.

I found my solution by using:

```
pattern = "/src=([^\\\"]+)/"
```

Answer (score 13):

I'd catch everything inside the quotes:

```
preg_match_all('/src="([^"]+)"/', $questArr_str, $images);
```

Comment: Only matches the first pattern.

Comment: `preg_match_all` "searches subject for all **matches**" – you don't need the `g` flag

Answer (score 8):

The parts that reads `([^\s]+)` means select anything that isn't a space.

Maybe try something like:

```
/src="([^"]+)"/
```

Which is select anything that isn't a double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to match `<img />` tag `src` attribute and or it content in `html/PHP` with regular expression.

Sample:

```
<img class="img img-responsive" title="publisher.PNG" src="media/projectx/agent/author/post/2/image/publisher.PNG" alt="" width="80%" />
```

To match just `src` attribute content use

```
preg_match("%(?<=src=\")([^\"])+(png|jpg|gif)%i",$input,$result)
```

`$result[0]` will output `media/projectx/agent/author/post/2/image/publisher.PNG`

To match `src' attribute and it content use

```
preg_match("%src=\"([^\"])+(png|jpg|gif)\"%i",$input,$result)
```

`$result[0]` will output `src="media/projectx/agent/author/post/2/image/publisher.PNG"`