# geting image url from a html img tag, using php

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

Not all src attribute in html, **Exactly the div ID begins with "post_message_"**

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="another_div">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/somfilename.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</div>
<div id="post_message_412">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/filename1.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</div>
<div id="post_message_413">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/filename2.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</div>
<div id="post_message_414">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/filename3.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</div>
<div id="post_message_415">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/filename4.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</div>
```

Get image tag's url with in the div ID begins with "post_message_" (Not like 'another_div' id name) using php preg_match() or preg_match_all() or preg_split() or any other possible solutions.

after that i want to get urls from an array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163958/regular-expression-to-find-src-attribute-of-html-img-element-in-php

Duplicate

Comment: This can be aced in a sec using jQuery. You'd have to use server-side script?

Comment: not all "src" attribute url in the html. exactly div ID begins with "post_message_"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML is the same structure as in your example, you can use: `<div\s*id="post_message_[^"]+">\s*<img src="([^"]+)`

It's only long because of the literals.

- `\s*` matches 0+ whitespace characters
- `[^"]+` matches characters that aren't `"`