# How do I configure aurelia.json to build for a CDN?

Tags: aurelia

I want to build my project so that it can be loaded from a CDN.

So on my page I'll have something like:

`<body aurelia-app="main">
  <script src="https://somecdn.com/scripts/vendor-bundle-a2d1fde206.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
</body>`

I think I need to change the baseDir values, but I don't know to what.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that by changing the aurelia.json. You would have to create a gulp task to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I created these manual functions to update all my references during the build in my `build.js`

```js
// this function needs to run BEFORE writeBundles
// so all the img src URLs can be prepended with the correct cdnUrl before being bundled
function replaceSourceCdnUrl() {
  if (!cdnUrl)
    return Promise.resolve();

  return gulp.src("src/**/*.*")
    // find img src attributes with either single or double quotes
    .pipe(replace(/img.*src=["']([^\\\"]+).*/g, function(match, p1) {
      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), url.resolve(cdnUrl, p1));
    }))
    // find img src.bind attributes with single quotes, to append double quoted cdn url
    .pipe(replace(/img.*src.bind='([^\\\"]+).*/g, function(match, p1) {
      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), `"${cdnUrl}" + ${p1}`);
    }))
    
    // find img src.bind attributes with double quotes, to append single quoted cdn url
    .pipe(replace(/img.*src.bind="([^\\\"]+).*/g, function(match, p1) {
      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), `'${cdnUrl}' + ${p1}`);
    }))
    
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/"));
}

function replaceCssCdnUrl() {
  if (!cdnUrl)
    return Promise.resolve();

  return gulp.src("css/**/*.*")
    // find url values in css files
    .pipe(replace(/url\(["'](.*)["']/g, function(match, p1) {
      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), url.resolve(cdnUrl, p1));
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("css/"));
}

// update the index file BEFORE AND AFTER writeBundles
// as the aurelia-cli.bundle searches for the exact output name when updating the revision bundle
// however it then uses path.posix.join() to update the index script src
// causing the cdnUrl to be updated with only 1 slash, i.e. http:/
function replaceIndexCdnUrl() {
  if (!cdnUrl)
    return Promise.resolve();

  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace#regex-replace-with-function-callback
  // regex - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190290/5954805
  let outputDir = project.build.targets[0].output;
  let scriptRegex = new RegExp(`script.*src=["']([^\\\"]*${outputDir}*).*`, "g");
  return gulp.src(project.build.targets[0].index)
    // find script src attribute
    .pipe(replace(scriptRegex, function(match, p1) {

      // https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix
      let posixPath = path.posix.join(cdnUrl, outputDir);
      let resolvedPath = url.resolve(cdnUrl, outputDir);

      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(posixPath, 'g'), resolvedPath).replace(p1, resolvedPath);
    }))

    //find link shortcut favicon
    .pipe(replace(/<link(?=.*rel="shortcut icon".*).*href=["']([^\\\"]+).*/g, function(match, p1) {
      return (p1.indexOf(cdnUrl) > -1) ? match : match.replace(new RegExp(p1, 'g'), url.resolve(cdnUrl, p1));
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
}
```

Then update your build's gulp tasks to execute these new functions and import the `path` and `url` dependencies

```js
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';

let build = gulp.series(
  gulp.parallel(
    replaceIndexCdnUrl,
    replaceSourceCdnUrl,
    replaceCssCdnUrl
  ),
  readProjectConfiguration,
  gulp.parallel(
    transpile,
    processMarkup,
    processCSS,
    copyFiles
  ),
  writeBundles,
  replaceIndexCdnUrl
);
```